# is-dropdown-submenu-parent makes links unclickable on Opera and Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, zurb-foundation

I am trying to make a website on foundation with dropdown menu.

However I noticed that when I click on some links there is an error on the console

> Uncaught TypeError: t.getBoundingClientRect is not a function
>
> ```
> at i (catalog-list-pack-d7c9d20e63.js:4)
> at Object.e [as ImNotTouchingYou] (catalog-list-pack-d7c9d20e63.js:4)
> at e.value (catalog-list-pack-d7c9d20e63.js:5)
> at HTMLLIElement.s (catalog-list-pack-d7c9d20e63.js:5)
> at HTMLLIElement.dispatch (catalog-list-pack-d7c9d20e63.js:2)
> at HTMLLIElement.y.handle (catalog-list-pack-d7c9d20e63.js:2)
> ```

This code that breaks is a plugin from foundation.

My debugging let me to the conclusion that if I remove the class `is-dropdown-submenu-parent` Everything works fine.

This class comes from foundation and I am afraid I am going to insert bugs somewhere else since I dont understand what is happening.

Another thing - it doesnt work only on Chrome and Opera. It works on Mozzila and even Microsoft Edge (the new Internet Explorer)

Here is the code on how the dropdown is created

```
<div class="MegaMenu__row">
     <div class="MegaMenu__listColumn">
       <dt class="is-dropdown-submenu-parent MegaMenu__item MegaMenu__item--
           header MegaMenu__item--no-bullet">
           <a href="/somewhere</a>
       </dt>
```

and below are more links which work.

About the code that breaks its minimized plugin and taking everything from it is tricky but here is the function that breaks. I have tried to make it a little bit more readable and I have no idea who Dave is.

```
   function f(t,e) {
      if(t=t.length?t[0]:t,t===window||t===document)
        throw new Error("I'm sorry, Dave. I'm afraid I can't do that.");
      var f=t.getBoundingClientRect(),
      o=t.parentNode.getBoundingClientRect(),
      i=document.body.getBoundingClientRect(),
      s=window.pageYOffset,
      h=window.pageXOffset;
    return{
            width:f.width,
            height:f.height,
            offset:{top:f.top+s,left:f.left+h},
            parentDims:{
                          width: o.width,
                          height: o.height,
                          offset{
                                   top:o.top+s,
                                   left:o.left+h
                                 }
                        },
            windowDims:{
                         width:i.width,
                         height:i.height,
                         offset:{
                                  top:s,
                                  left:h
                                 }
                        }
           }
    }
```

Can someone explain to me why that js function breaks on Opera and Chrome?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Nope....I was just like "not gonna fix that". Not my problem now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case it helps anyone, we were getting the same error on the same browsers as the OP but in our case, it was happening when the user resized the viewport.

The reason turned out to be a dropdown menu that did not have a corresponding parent to trigger it.

For instance:

```
<li data-toggle="someDropDown">
    <a href="#">OPEN DROPDOWN</a>
</li>

<div id="someDropDown" data-dropdown  data-resize="someDropDown" data-events="resize">
    <div>The dropdown</div>
</div>
```

This works fine as is. If I remove the first `li` from the code, Foundation throws an error when the window is resized.

In other words, this is a bug in Foundation 6. It should handle cases when a dropdown menu subscribes to the resize event and the parent is missing.